# How can I route api gateway endpoint to ec2 private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed django app on ec2.I am only allowed to use private IP for ec2. So my endpoint is only accessible in our vpn. Now there is requirement like some of external applications want to use some of backend endpoints of that django application. So we want to have open endpoint secured with mechanism like apikey.  Is there any way to do this? I am thinking like creating api endpoint which will route to the ec2 enpoint. But Not sure how we can allow apigateway to access that endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that through [API Gateway private integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html). This will require you to setup `VpcLink` between your API and VPC, as well as  **Network Load Balancer** (NLB) which the API connects to. The NLB then will connect to your private EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this but I am getting this error while creating vpc links `User does not have sufficient permissions to create VPC endpoint services.` Is there any other way or can you share the permission list that i will need.

Comment: @user11823877 I would suggest to make new question, specific to the permission issues. In the question you can provide the relevant details of your setup, full error message, when does this error exactly occurs, and more.